# Looking for repeating patterns in integer numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to find repeating patterns in integer numbers. To do that I use vectors that store each digit individually. I want to write the whole thing as a function that prints out the repeating patterns of the number. The numbers are mostly 12 digits long.

An example:
The number is 057 987 051 2057
I want the function to print out:
057
05
It should also only print out the longest recurrent pattern. I'm currently stuck on how to implement the whole thing in C++. I would also like to know if there are any libraries that support the feature I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = m_number.begin(); it != m_number.end(); ++it) {
    int follower = *(it + 1);
    for (vector<int>::iterator jt = it + 1; jt != m_number.end(); ++jt) {
        if (*jt == *it) {
            if (*(jt + 1) == follower)
                cout << *jt;
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
```

This is what I've tried so far. This here obviously doesn't work yet but I hope it gives you an idea about what I want the function to do. I try to use two for-loops that iterate over the m_number vector (that contains the integer number I'm trying to check btw.).

Comment: Hello. It seems you're new here. Usually to get help you'll have to show you what you tried, how it failed and what you were expecting.

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Another idea: `std::rotate` the vector of digits and find common prefixes.

Comment: If it has to be efficient, consider using a suffix tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use something like:

```
std::set<std::vector<int>> GetRepetitingPatterns(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::set<std::vector<int>> res;
    for (std::size_t size = v.size() - 1; size != 0; --size) {
        std::set<std::vector<int>> s;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i + size != v.size() + 1; ++i) {
            auto [it, inserted] = s.emplace(v.begin() + i, v.begin() + i + size);
            if (!inserted) {
                res.insert(*it);
            }
        }
#if 1 // Longest only
        if (!res.empty()) {
            return res;   
        }
#endif
    }
    return {};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d32c089088b1d3a)

and for variation (all/longest and min size):
[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c02edae0ed04774c)

Comment: Thanks for answering but the demo doesn't seem to work for me tho

Comment: Need C++17, link changed.

Comment: Thanks! But this implementation only prints out "057" but the pattern "05" also occurs and should be printed out

Comment: [Other demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c02edae0ed04774c) that you can customize with parameter..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I chose your solution because it's the closest to what I've already tried and had in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Indeed, forgot than it can repeat with part of itself. Fixed code.

Comment: started to have second thoughts about my comment so I was just about to test what the outcome would be. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first way of doing it :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < m_numbers.size(); i++) {
    // Look for patterns starting everywhere in the following numbers
    for (size_t j = i+1; j < m_numbers.size(); j++) {
      // Pattern storing
      std::vector<int> pattern;

      // Condition to stop the search
      bool valid_pattern = true;

      // Variable for the while loop
      int offset = 0;
      while (valid_pattern && j+offset < m_numbers.size()) {
        // If the numbers are equal, continue the pattern, else, stop the search
        if(m_numbers[i+offset] == m_numbers[j+offset]){
          pattern.push_back(m_numbers[i+offset]);
        } else {
          valid_pattern = false;
        }
        offset++;
      }

      // If the pattern has at least two numbers, output it to the console
      if(pattern.size() > 1){
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < pattern.size(); idx++) {
          std::cout << pattern[idx];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to start with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::string str = "0579870512057";
    // a map of substrings and the number of times they appear
    std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> pm;

    for(auto a=str.begin(); a!=str.end()-1; ++a) {
        for(auto b=a+1; b!=str.end(); ++b) {
            // std::string(a, b+1) creates the substring from your iterators
            // the unordered_map::operator[] creates a key, value pair
            // if the key doesn't exist (value is default constructed)
            // ++ increases the value by 1
            ++pm[ std::string(a, b+1) ];
        }
    }
    // display the number of times each substring appears (if it appeared more than once)
    // and display the length (size) of each
    for(auto& p : pm) {
        if(p.second>1)
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << p.second << " "
                      << std::setw(12) << p.first.size() << " " << p.first << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

A slightly more complicated way is to create a custom `set` that keeps the recurring patterns sorted from longest to shortest but it has the advantage that you'll know that the first pattern in the result will be the longest. It also does not make any copies of the original input except for the patterns found.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct comp { // a custom comparison class to sort the result
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        if(b.size()==a.size()) return a < b; // lowest "value" when length is equal
        else return b.size() < a.size();     // but longest pattern goes first
    }      // note  b  before  a  when comparing sizes
};

using string_pattern_set = std::set<std::string, comp>; // custom set type using "comp"

string_pattern_set get_recurring_patterns(const std::string& str) {
    string_pattern_set sorted_result;

    for(size_t len=str.size()-1; len>0; --len) {
        auto end = str.end()-len;
        for(auto pos=str.begin(); pos<end; ++pos) {
            for(auto check=pos+1; check<=end; ++check) {
                if(std::equal(pos, pos+len, check)) {
                    sorted_result.emplace(pos, pos+len);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sorted_result;
}

int main() {
    string_pattern_set res = get_recurring_patterns("0579870512057");
    if(res.size())
        std::cout << "the longest recurring pattern is "
                  << res.begin()->size() << " char(s)\n";
    // display all patterns from longest to shortest
    for(auto& str : res) std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

---

A third option, if you are really worried about memory consumption, would be to not store the recurring strings at all but to store the `begin` and `end` iterators for the matching substrings. This approach works well when the recurring patterns are expected to be long and plentiful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// type to store begin and end iterators for matching patterns
using strits = std::pair<std::string::const_iterator, std::string::const_iterator>;

struct comp { // a custom comparison class to sort the result
    bool operator()(const strits& a, const strits& b) const {
        if((b.second-b.first)==(a.second-a.first)) // lowest "value" when length is equal
            return std::lexicographical_compare(a.first, a.second, b.first, b.second);
        else // but longest pattern goes first
            return (b.second-b.first) < (a.second-a.first);
    }      // note  b  before            a  when comparing sizes
};

using string_pattern_set = std::set<strits, comp>; // custom set type using "comp"

template<bool LONGEST_ONLY = false, bool BIG_STRING = false>
string_pattern_set get_recurring_patterns(const std::string& str) {
    string_pattern_set sorted_result;

    for(size_t len=str.size()-1; len>0; --len) {
        auto end = str.end()-len;
        for(auto begin=str.begin(); begin<end; ++begin) {
            if constexpr (BIG_STRING) {
                // skip patterns already found to be recurring.
                // in C++20, use set::contains instead
                if(sorted_result.find(strits(begin, begin+len))!=sorted_result.end())
                    continue;
            }
            for(auto check=begin+1; check<=end; ++check) {
                if(std::equal(begin, begin+len, check)) {
                    sorted_result.emplace(begin, begin+len);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if constexpr (LONGEST_ONLY)
            if(!sorted_result.empty()) break;
    }
    return sorted_result;
}

int main() {
    string_pattern_set res = get_recurring_patterns("0579870512057");

    if(res.size()) {
        const auto& [begin, end] = *res.begin();
        std::cout << "the longest recurring pattern is "
                  << (end - begin)<< " char(s)\n";
    }

    // display all patterns from longest to shortest
    for(const auto& [begin, end] : res) {
        std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe note that having `O(N^2)` memory usage could be quite bad in the case of long strings.

Comment: 12 characters long will create at most 78 map entries. I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a question, what exactly does "size_t" in line 8 do? Also I never used maps before so I'm new to the concept of maps thus I'm also having quite a hard time figuring out what "p.second" and "p.first" for example do.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sure .... But its bigO, so i am not worried about 12 characters, i am worried about how the solution scales. 64 will use 4kb, 128 will use 16kb! One you get to 1024 (not an outrages string length) we have 1mb!!! Not very scale able...

Comment: @Xetron `size_t` is an unsigned integer type suitable for arbitrary lengths and indexes of things you have in memory, but it's overkilll for this. Even an unsigned char could have been used as a counter. `p.first`: When you iterate over an `unordered_map` you get a `std::pair<key, value>`. `p.first` is the key (substring in this case) and `p.second` is the value (the count in this case).

Comment: @Xetron If something is reasonably fast and simple and capable of doing the task at hand there's no need to complicate it. 12 figures was the max and it would work even it was suddenly changed to the double, If the problem becomes more complex, say you have 1 million figures, then it calls for a more complex solution.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox got the tag wrong for the comment above :-)